# Magento observer is not viewing product details

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have created custom `checkout_cart_save_before` observer in magento by create the following files

**app/etc/modules/Cart_Override.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cart_Override>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Contacts />
            </depends>
        </Cart_Override>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Cart/Override/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cartoverride>
                <class>Cart_Override_Model</class>
            </cartoverride>
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <cart_override_qty_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Cart_Override_Model_Qtyc_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkout_cart_save_before</method>
                    </cart_override_qty_observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_save_before>     
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

and **app/code/local/Cart/Override/Model/Qtyc/Observer.php**

```
class Cart_Override_Model_Qtyc_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{

    public function checkout_cart_save_before($observer)
    {
        $action  = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($product);
        echo "</pre>";
        die();
    }

}
```

The observer is working fine, when i click the add to cart button it is going to `checkout_cart_save_before` function. But i could not get the product values from the observer using the following code inside the `checkout_cart_save_before` function

```
$product = $observer->getProduct();
```

I have to add something for get the `product details` from the `observer` parameter?....any guess??

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::save()` where the event is dispatched:

```
 Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_save_before', array('cart'=>$this));
```

You can access the cart data with `$cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();` and the quote items with `$cart->getItems()`.